# TYPE the contents of all the E**01 files in the a folder and redirect in command prompt

Tags: command-line

Sorry learning command prompt and need assistance.  Is there a command for:

TYPE the contents of all the E**01 files in a folder and redirect the output (>) to create a file in the "expenses" folder called All01.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b E??01.*') do @type %a >> Expenses\All01.txt
```